# Why does the jobs command not work in shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, job-control, jobs

If I run `jobs -l` on command prompt it shows me the status of running jobs but if I run below file ./tmp.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
jobs -l
```

It shows empty output.

Why is that and how can I obtain information about a status of a particular job inside of a shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jobs`

shows the jobs [managed by the current shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html). Your script runs inside its own shell, so `jobs` there will only show jobs managed by the script's shell...

To see this in action, run

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60 &
jobs -l
```

To see information about "jobs" started before a shell script, inside the script, you need to treat them like regular processes, and use `ps` etc. You can limit yourself to processes started by the parent shell (the shell from which the script was started, if any) by using the `$PPID` variable inside the script, and looking for processes sharing the same parent PID.

Comment: thanks. could you also answer `how can I obtain information about a status of a particular job inside of a shell script?`

Comment: (i'll accept your answer later in case someone has a better method) by the way, can it happen that the process id gets assigned to some other process by the system, after the original process is done? it could create a confusion then!

Comment: PIDs are recycled, yes. Looking at the issue more generally, to manage groups of processes together, you could use process groups or cgroups, but that feels like it's outside the scope of your question...

Answer (score 2):

Like Stephen said, spawning a new shell is probably not what you want to do. You have to run the code in the **current shell**.

Your code would work by either doing `source myscript.sh` or declaring your code in a [function](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) (which could be in your bashrc or a separate file that is sourced).

```
myfunction () {
  jobs -l
}
```

I used this in [my dotfiles](https://github.com/jasonszhao/dotfiles/blob/master/shell/aliases.zsh#L83), if you're interested.